# Make a calendar displayable on all (not all actually) clients

Tags: java, ios, google-calendar-api, icalendar, ical4j

I need to create a calendar and then send this calendar via e-mail as an attachment. After some study, I found out the best way is to send the calendar not as a file-attachment but modifying the content-type of the body part of the mail to `text-calendar`. I have to provide compatibility for

1. Gmail
2. Android (using gmail)
3. iOS Calendar
4. Outlook

The look&feel I have to provide resembles the one you can have on Gmail, so with accept/decline link. The solution I found works fine on Gmail, Outlook (and other clients such as Thunderbird), but not on iOS or Android (at least on old version prior to 4.0.3 where you can install the Google Calendar app). Basically, iOS does not show accept/decline links by default, but you have to click on the attachment (no matter which way I send the calendar, setting the content-type to `text/calendar` generates the mail client of iOS to display a `mime-attachment.ics`) to be able to add the calendar to your personal calendar. 
My approach now is to convert the ics file to some html, and format the body of the e-mail with a `multipart/alernative` "field" (sorry, I don't have a better term for this) so that clients which understand `text/calendar` will show that part, while clients which don't understand it will show the html part. Now, my question is: how do I generate the links? For instance, I extracted a link and it looks like

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=RESPOND&amp;eid=long_eid;rst=1&amp;tok=less_long_tok&amp;ctz=Europe/Rome&amp;hl=en" style="color:#20c;white-space:nowrap" itemprop="url">Yes</a>
```

How do I generate the `eid` and the `tok`? It seems to me they are some sort of hash code or anyway some sort of code.
On the other hand, if you know about a better approach to generate the calendar and having it to work on at least the clients I mentioned earlier feel free to suggest. I generate the calendar with `ical4j` and even if I would prefer not to change, I will if I can produce higher quality code.
Thanks in advance